# Complexity of finding the smallest well-covered completion

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-algorithms

This is related to an earlier question on [which graphs have the property that all maximal independent sets are maximum](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7645/maximal-maximum-independent-sets) — such graphs turn out to be known as the [well-covered graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-covered_graph). Any graph $G$ is an induced subgraph of a well-covered graph: for instance, find a clique cover of $G$, and add one more vertex to each of the cliques in the cover. Smaller clique covers lead to well-covered supergraphs of $G$ with fewer vertices. Which leads to the following problem:

Input: a graph $G$ and a number $k$

Output: yes if $G$ is an induced subgraph of a $k$-vertex well-covered graph, no otherwise

What is known if anything about the complexity of this problem? Testing whether a graph is well-covered is coNP-complete, so the obvious complexity class for finding a small well-covered completion is $\Sigma^P_2$ — but is it complete for $\Sigma^P_2$?

Comment: is this similar to [kalai's idea](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/14910/7884), "It will be interesting to understand graphs where this property [well covered] holds for all induced subgraphs"?